# How to extract dyld_shared_cache from non-jailbroken device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I want to Reversing the iOS 12 dyld_shared_cache file.
But, i don't know how to extract iOS 12 dyld_shared_cache file from non-jailbroken device.
Is it some way to extract that file?

Comment: You can just download an IPSW (links available [here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Firmware/iPhone/12.x) or [here](https://ipsw.me/)), unzip them, mount the biggest dmg file (the one that's multiple GB) and navigate to `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an application that, basically, does this:

```
NSString* documents = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
[NSFileManager.defaultManager copyItemAtPath:@"/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_arm64" 
                              toPath:[documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cache"]]
```

Enable iTunes file sharing in Info.plist of the application and you can grab the file using iTunes.

Comment: Note that for A12 devices, the cache file is named `dyld_shared_cache_arm64e`.